# PlaceHolderFormat doesn't replace the dollar sign for the parameter value during SQL using pgx driver for postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, pgx

I am new to Go and am trying to check a password against a username in a postgresql database.

I can't get dollar substitution to occur and would rather not resort to concatenating strings.

I am currently using squirrel but also tried it without and didn't have much luck.

I have the following code:

```
    package datalayer

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    sq "github.com/Masterminds/squirrel"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var (
    // for the database
    db *sql.DB
)

func InitDB(sqlDriver string, dataSource string) error {
    var err error

    // Connect to the postgres db  (sqlDriver is literal string "pgx")
    db, err = sql.Open(sqlDriver, dataSource)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return db.Ping()
}

// Create a struct that models the structure of a user, both in the request body, and in the DB
type Credentials struct {
    Password string `json:"password", db:"password"`
    Username string `json:"username", db:"username"`
}

func Signin(c *gin.Context) {
    // Parse and decode the request body into a new `Credentials` instance
    creds := &Credentials{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(creds)


    if err != nil {
        // If there is something wrong with the request body, return a 400 status
        c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    query := sq.
        Select("password").
        From("users").
        Where("username = $1", creds.Username).
        PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

        // The line below doesn't substitute the $ sign, it shows this:  SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = $1 [rgfdgfd] <nil>
    fmt.Println(sq.
        Select("password").
        From("users").
        Where("username = $1", creds.Username).
        PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar).ToSql())

    rows, sqlerr := query.RunWith(db).Query()
    if sqlerr != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("QueryRow failed: %v", sqlerr))
    }

    if err != nil {
        // If there is an issue with the database, return a 500 error
        c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    // We create another instance of `Credentials` to store the credentials we get from the database
    storedCreds := &Credentials{}
    // Store the obtained password in `storedCreds`
    err = rows.Scan(&storedCreds.Password)
    if err != nil {
        // If an entry with the username does not exist, send an "Unauthorized"(401) status
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        // If the error is of any other type, send a 500 status
        c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Compare the stored hashed password, with the hashed version of the password that was received
    if err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(storedCreds.Password), []byte(creds.Password)); err != nil {
        // If the two passwords don't match, return a 401 status
        c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }
    fmt.Printf("We made it !")
    // If we reach this point, that means the users password was correct, and that they are authorized
    // The default 200 status is sent
}
```

I see the following when I check pgAdmin, which shows the dollar sign not being substituted:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution of the placeholders is done by the postgres server, it SHOULD NOT be the job of the Go code, or squirrel, to do the substitution.

When you are executing a query that takes parameters, a rough outline of what the database driver has to do is something like the following:

1. Using the query string, with placeholders untouched, a `parse` request is sent to the postgres server to create a *prepared statement*.
2. Using the parameter values and the identifier of the newly-created statement, a `bind` request is sent to make the statement ready for execution by creating a *portal*. A portal (similar to, but not the same as, a cursor) represents a ready-to-execute or already-partially-executed statement, with any missing parameter values filled in.
3. Using the portal's identifier an `execute` request is sent to the server which then executes the portal's query.

*Note that the above steps are just a rough outline, in reality there are more request-response cycles involved between the db client and server.*

And as far as `pgAdmin` is concerned I believe what it is displaying to you is the prepared statement as created by the `parse` request, although I can't tell for sure as I am not familiar with it.

---

In theory, a helper library like `squirrel`, or a driver library like `pgx`, could implement the substitution of parameters themselves and then send a simple query to the server. In general, however, given the possibility of SQL injections, it is better to leave it to the authority of the postgres server, in my opinion.

---

The `PlaceholderFormat`'s job is to simply translate the placeholder to the specified format. For example you could write your SQL using the MySQL format `(?,?,...)` and then invoke the `PlaceholderFormat(sql.Dollar)` method to translate that into the PostgreSQL format `($1,$2,...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I also suspect the postgres server isn't setup correctly to make the substitution but I can find little on what specific configuration allows for this.  Strangely enough the same postgres server performs dollar substitution when I use the pgx driver and so I ultimately have had to settle for this.

Comment: @PaulRyan You misunderstand the purpose of the `ToSql` method. You have this comment in the code example: `The line below doesn't substitute the $ sign, it shows this:  SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = $1 [rgfdgfd] <nil>`. Well, it doesn't do the substitution because it is NOT its job. Its job is to build the query string. The substitution of parameters is the job of the postgres server, and the postgres server DOES that job very well. There is nothing wrong with your postgres server. What's wrong is your understanding of what `ToSql` should do.

Comment: I probably haven't diagnosed the underlying problem here but I added ToSql in the hope of gaining some insight as to what was happening not because I believe it was required to perform substitution. Ultimately pgAdmin gives me the same results with or without my addition of ToSql

Comment: @PaulRyan the question is, do you have an actual problem? Does your query not return the rows you expected it to return? Do the `Scan` or `Query` methods return an error? If none of the above. If everything is working as it should, then there isn't really a problem is there? Note also that the screenshot of pgAdmin shows the `pg_stat_activity` view, that view's `query` column contains the *text* of the query executed, which in your case is the *correct* text of the prepared statement.

Comment: @PaulRyan unless you can find, somewhere in the official documentation of PostgreSQL, that the `pg_stat_activity.query` column should contain the executed query with placeholders substituted for actual values, you might as well assume that what you see there is the correct output and there is nothing wrong, not with the server, and not with the client.

Comment: Now I get you. From what you are saying I can't really be certain the cause is ineffective dollar substitution.

Comment: @PaulRyan Yes. It is safe to assume that it is *by design* that the query text in `pg_stat_activity.query` retains the placeholders.